# Coleman 2-burner Camp Chef stove leaks: Can't find suitable seal

Tags: camping, cooking, stoves, canister-stoves

A 15-year-old square o-ring has deteriorated to the point that it can't hold the seal, and propane leaks around it. I have exhausted myself searching for a suitable replacement.

The seal in question is part of the stove, not the regulator. It's on the nipple which the regulator pipe threads onto when connecting the regulator pipe to the stove.

The branding on the stove is "Coleman" and "Camp Chef," and model markings say "Mountain Series" and "Everest." It's about 15 years old and uses those 1-pound green propane bottles.

Is anyone aware of a way to get a replacement for this ring seal? I've trolled Coleman, Amazon and a bunch of different o-ring retailers and manufacturers. I'm honestly considering fabricating one if I can't find one. Without it the stove is un-useable, it just seems obscene to throw it away.

Comment: Any chance you can supply photos? Also have you tried reaching out to their customer support, rather than just the website?

Comment: Are you sure it's a square o-ring?  Or could it be a round one deformed into a square?

Comment: Be sure to use one without grease. Hydrocarbons don't play nicely with the grease on o-rings. And +1 for a square seal. Can you show us the aperture/fitting into/onto which the o-ring will fit?

Comment: @spikey_richie liquid fuel stoves often use silicone grease; it might also be used in gas stoves

Comment: If you measure it properly I'm sure a generic O-ring supplier will sell you one (or more likely a bag of 10, but not for too much)

Comment: @chris what I mean is, a generic o-ring kit from a hardware store may have been greased with something incompatible with hydrocarbon based cylinders. It's just something to consider.

Comment: @spikey_richie they're supplied dry from  the hardware stores around here, but I didn't mean a hardware store, I meant an o ring supplier. Hardware stores are useless except for sizes commonly used in domestic plumbing and aren't worth consideration